# Dynamic Tabs in Android

Tags: android

How do i create dynamic tabs in Android. From a list view, i click on an item and depending on the item i need to show n number of tabs. Each tabs should use the same activity used by the 1st tab. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

TabHost has a method TabHost.addTab(TabSpec tabSpec) . Use that to add any number of tabs at runtime. You can also change the name and image of the tabIndicators at run time.